# Suddenly this error is occuring: "you must call 'the_content' function" when trying to edit in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a wordpress page with woocommerce that worked perfectly. However, something happened so that I cannot edit some pages with Elementor anymore, for example, the Home page.

I am using Porto theme but I have tried to enable default themes and even they are listed and the folders are present, Wordpress does not find them :-(